# Arduino hanging on upload

Tags: arduino, arduino-uno

Getting this when I upload the blink example from the arduino getting started book.  The file compiles but just hangs at this point.  I have reset, restarted, reinstalled.  Nothing seems to work.

It worked just 1 day ago and there have been no changes since.

```
 System wide configuration file is "C:\Program Files (x86)\Arduino/hardware/tools/avr/etc/avrdude.conf"

 Using Port                    : COM5
 Using Programmer              : avr109
 Overriding Baud Rate          : 57600
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Most of the problems with uploading sketches to Arduino boards come down to communication problems.
Try using other USB ports, check if you selected the correct COM port in the Arduino IDE, also check that you selected the correct board in the IDE.

If all else fails, please check if you can upload the sketch on another PC.

Answer (score 0):

this error might be caused from a mistake in connecting the wires or a problem in the program.So try to check the connection of the wires and if you uploaded the program just because you still don't know how to write arduino codes, I advise you to learn and experiment with the help of the tutorials on the arduino site and reference.I hope that my answer helped you.